# Not able to access SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, windows-server-2012-r2

I am trying to access Microsoft SQL Server 2014 using "SQL Server Authentication". But even after entering the correct credentials, it says the following.

```
C:\Users\morry>sqlcmd -S aana\sqlexpress -U ragunath
Password: Sqlcmd: Error: Microsoft ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server : Login failed
for user 'ragunath'..
```

On the UI, it says the following:

```
Cannot connect to AANA\SQLEXPRESS.

------------------------------
**ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**

A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: Shared Memory Provider, error: 0 - No process is on the other end of the pipe.) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 233)

No process is on the other end of the pipe
```

What could be wrong here? Why am I not able to access the server when I am using the correct credentials?

Comment: What is the authentication mode of the server instance?

Comment: SQL Server Authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Since it's not a TCP connection problem I think you should try to specify a 'database default' for the account you're having issues with. You can try the following: log in to the SQL server using any other admin account (be it with Windows authentication or SQL server authentication), go to the security folder> logins> choose the account (sqlexpress in your case) and then specify the default database for that account. I'm seeing this might be the issue because as there's no default for the account the service doesn't know where to connect the user. Hope it can resolve the issue.

Comment: Default database is already set for the user. I don't think this is the issue in my case.